# ng build --prod throwing errr

Tags: angular, build, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I am using `ng build --prod` command but it is showing error like

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\allud\MyCafe\src'
resolve './app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\allud\MyCafe\src'
  using description file: C:\Users\allud\MyCafe\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: C:\Users\allud\MyCafe\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    using description file: C:\Users\allud\MyCafe\package.json (relative path: ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\allud\MyCafe\src\app\app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\allud\MyCafe\src\app\app.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\allud\MyCafe\src\app\app.module.ngfactory.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        C:\Users\allud\MyCafe\src\app\app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
[C:\Users\allud\MyCafe\src\app\app.module.ngfactory]
[C:\Users\allud\MyCafe\src\app\app.module.ngfactory.ts]
[C:\Users\allud\MyCafe\src\app\app.module.ngfactory.js]
[C:\Users\allud\MyCafe\src\app\app.module.ngfactory]
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-66
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Comment: can you post your code as well??

Comment: i have not coded anything yet. i have just started with ng new myCafe , cd myCafe, followed by  ng build --prod. which is throwing error.  ng serve properly working so there is no problem with code as yet.

Comment: which version of `anglular` and `CLI`?

Comment: angular cli version 1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Seems line node caching module issue. 
Please try below given commands:

```
cd {your-project}
npm -f cache clean 
rm -f package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

If it does not work clean you .npm and .node-gyp in the home directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can verify,

1. Check whether you are loading the components from the correct directory, I mean the path of the components in `Import` statements

   ```
   import PackageName from './FromFolder';
   ```
2. Remove node_modules and reinstall all the packages
3. Update your Angular CLI version with updated packages

Now try `ng build --prod`